# Increasing mean deviation with increasing sample size on Excel's NORMINV()

Tags: excel, math, random, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have a strange behaviour in my attempt to code Excel's NORMINV() in C. As norminv() I took [this](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/impl/sprouse/ltqnorm.c) function from a mathematician, it's probably correct since I also tried different ones with same result. Here's the code:

```
double calculate_probability(double x0, double x1)
{
    return x0 + (x1 - x0) * rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX);
}

int main() {

long double probability = 0.0;
long double mean = 0.0;
long double stddev = 0.001;
long double change_percentage = 0.0;
long double current_price = 100.0;
srand(time(0));
int runs = 0;
long double prob_sum = 0.0;
long double price_sum = 0.0;

while (runs < 100000)
{
    probability = calculate_probability(0.00001, 0.99999);
    change_percentage = mean + stddev * norminv(probability); //norminv(p, mu, sigma) = mu + sigma * norminv(p)
    current_price = current_price * (1.0 + change_percentage);
    runs++;
    prob_sum += probability;
    price_sum += current_price;
}
printf("\n\n%f %f\n", price_sum / runs, prob_sum / runs);
return 0;
}
```

Now I want to simulate Excel's NORMINV(rand(), 0, 0.001) where rand() is a value > 0 and < 1, 0 is the mean and 0.001 would be the standard deviation.

With 1000 values it looks okay:
100.729780 0.501135

With 10000 values it spreads too much:
107.781909 0.502301

And with 100000 values it sometimes spreads even more:
87.876500 0.498738

Now I don't know why that happens. My assumption is that the random number generator has to be normally distributed, too. In my case `probability` is calculated fine since the mean is pretty much 0.5 all the time. Thus I don't know why the mean deviation is increasing. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why is that spread "too much"? With the tiny stddev you use, what you're doing is very close to an additive random walk with steps that have a standard deviation of 0.1 (0.1 == 100.0 * 0.001). If you take N steps, I would expect the final value to have a standard deviation of sqrt(N)*0.1. If anything, the 1000 step answer looks surprisingly close to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something along the lines of a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk), except your moves are with a multiplicative scaling factor rather than additive steps.

Consider two successive moves, the first of which gives 20% inflation, the second with 20% deflation.  Starting with a baseline of 100, after the first step you're at 120.  If you now take 80% of 120, you get 96 rather than the original 100.  In other words, seemingly symmetric scaling factors are not actually symmetric.  While your scaling factors are random, they are still being created symmetrically around 1, so I'm not surprised to see deviations accumulate.

Comment: Can you explain to me where the problem in the code is located? Is is norminv() itself? calculate_probability() should be ok, right? I'm wondering because in Excel there is no such thing as a mean deviation and actually I'm doing just the same. Since change_percentage is negative in 50% of the cases I don't see what you mean exactly.

Comment: The problem is that `100 * (1 + 0.2) * (1 - 0.2) = 96 != 100`.  When the "symmetric" deviations get added or subtracted to a scale factor and multiplied, they are not symmetric.  Two deviations, that you probably thought were symmetric and would bring you back to one hundred, don't balance.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, just wonder how my code differs from the norminv() implementation in excel, seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ot7HOI3wQE).

Comment: I see nothing in that video that should point to results any different from what you're getting.